# Ability to move questions from per site Meta to MSE (this site)

Tags: feature-request, migration, meta, per-site-meta

I think there should be an option to move from a per site Meta of any Stack Exchange site, to the general meta Stack Exchange (this one).

Comment: Moderators *can* move the question, if they feel it is appropriate, so this already exists.

Comment: We absolutely need this option, and the corresponding one to move things the other direction.

Answer (score 13):

Generally speaking, posting any feature-request, bug report, or general discussion to the **per-site metas** is perfectly appropriate for just about any situation. We are set up in a way so that these post are *not* relegated with second-class treatment.

If a post comes up that can *truly* benefit from a broader discussion by the entire network (i.e. something we've never seen nor discussed before), then the per-site moderators can move it.

But in general, we don't really expect the average user to understand (or have to learn about) all the nuances of what support should go where. Users simply want an answer to their question (or to suggest a feature, or report a bug) without being given the runaround about where they should have posted it.

**So, no,** I would prefer ***not*** to have an explicit *"this belongs on meta SE"* feature. Users should feel perfectly welcome to **discuss issues that affect *their* site with their peer group** without having their conversation whisked away for an audience they may not have even been aware of before posting. It could even be harmful to the conversation.

Comment: I think the point about SE having the tooling now to fully keep tabs on per-site meta activity is often overlooked, which leads people to believe that only things here will be actioned on (and that's not true). Per-site metas also have the benefit of being less...reactive about certain issues, making it a better first step for most people.