# Is it OK to create a new question asking about code in an old answer instead of waiting until my reputation is 50?

Tags: support, reputation, questions, answers, new-questions

I have a question about code that's in an old Stack Overflow answer. Is it OK to post a new question asking about that code instead if waiting until my reputation is over 50? If my reputation was over 50 I would not be asking this Meta question because I would have commented.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850680/how-to-extract-the-cartesian-coordinates-x-y-of-an-svg-image) interesting Stack Overflow question. I have a very specific question about [the answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851533/3773011) Python script where it reads `print(type(obj).__name__,[and so on and so on]`.

I'm unsure if it's something that could have been asked of the answer author with a comment on the answer, but my account has less than 50 reputation, so that's not an option for me.

Yes, I could work to get my reputation up, and shall. However, it is bad form to ask a new question about the issue? In the meantime, I shall search around for what I need, but figured this came up enough it wouldn't hurt to ask: posting questions about SO posts because the user account is <50.

Please note I am not complaining about the reputation needed for posting comments. In fact, I think it is a good idea.

Comment: Yes this is bad and would get deleted quickly. (plus lots of downvotes and closure of course, greatly improving risk of question ban.)

Comment: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/353058)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/282094) -   "Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not make an attempt to answer the question asked.".

Comment: @Rob sure but I was essentially trying to make a rep<50 comment on an old question by posting a new question!

Comment: While at least one of the proposed duplicates probably should be edited to include something that's an effective answer to this question, neither of them currently have anything saying what action should be taken in this situation. The proposed duplicates cover the fact that a comment shouldn't be posted as an answer, but *don't* say anything about what someone *should* do if they have a question about the code provided in an answer, which is what this question is asking about. There might be a duplicate for this, but those proposed so far don't, currently, answer this, so aren't duplicates.

Comment: @Bryan, new questions need to ensure that they wouldn't be answered by the existing question, nor can they be an *answer* to that question, they should be a comment. --- See the FAQ:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/282094 "... the guidelines for closing a question as a duplicate are much broader on meta sites, and allow for closures where main sites do not. For instance, a question can be closed as a duplicate of another question that is  ...  a duplicate of the broader one.".

Comment: Never a thread. [Just a single question and one  or more answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). Why do you think I changed my user name here?

Comment: "I do not know the proper name" So find out. Meanwhile, how do you expect us to know what you are talking about if you only use a word or two instead of a clear specific description? This post has a lot of other unclear references to things & appearances of terms.

Comment: This seems like it's starting to become a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232296/1017231

Comment: @bobble very close - so I made a note about reputation in the title. If my reputation allowed comments, I would never have asked.

Comment: @bobble ...  And a user asked about the reputation 50 waiting issue with no reply. And the answers there - yes ask - contradict answers here - ask and it will be deleted.

Comment: user @DineshM made this point - wait until reputation 50 v. ask new question that links to old answer.

Answer (score 13):

Questions are for actual questions. Answers are for actual answers. Comments are primarily to be used to request or suggest improvements to the post, including asking for clarification or suggesting the post be edited to provide more explanation, additional information, etc.

If you have a real question about the meaning of a specific part of code in a specific answer, that might be appropriate as a comment asking for clarification, or as a complete new question, depending on the scope of the question you have. Given that you haven't told us what you're actual question is, it's difficult for us to make a determination. It's also possible, even likely, that what you're wondering about has been asked previously, perhaps with a bit different context. So, be sure to search for existing questions first. Given that you don't have the 50 reputation to post a comment, your only real option for posting a question is to post an actual question.

What would be really bad would be to post a new *answer* which asked a question about the code in another post, as answer posts are *strictly* for actual answers to the question on which they are posted. Such non-answer posts are typically downvoted, flagged as Not an Answer, and deleted

If you do create a new question post, then make sure that it's self-contained. In other words, it needs to contain enough information/code for people to know what you're asking about without the *need* for them to click a link to somewhere else. You should, however, include a link back to the original answer containing the code you're asking about, so that people have more context, but not as a substitute for having the code in your question. If you're copying code from that answer, which you probably should do, given you're asking about it, then you need to follow our referencing requirements when you include the code as text in your question. Our referencing requirements are detailed in the "[How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)" page in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).